# How do I stop the text in a Winforms textbox from being automatically selected/highlighted when first displayed?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, highlight

In the case where I don't want a user to inadvertently delete text displayed in a textbox when the textbox is first loaded and displayed, e.g., by inadvertently fumble-fingering on the keyboard, how do I stop the text in the textbox from being automatically selected when first displayed and before the user has access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//set SelectionStart property to zero
//This clears the selection and sets the cursor to the left of the 1st character in the textbox
textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;

//This clears the selection and sets the cursor to the end of whatever is in the textbox
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the tabstop property of textbox **false** for which you want to disable the highlight do -

```
textBox1.TabStop = false;
```

This will stop highlighting the text of your textbox.

Comment: This does work, but then the cursor is invisible when the dialog appears. I'm thinking it should be visible in the text box

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the exact problem you are facing now

Comment: oh, sorry - no problem. My intent was to answer my own question for the purpose of making the knowledge available so that others (including myself) can find it later. I have to wait two days to answer my own question.